# Export picture share list from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, export, facebook-page

I started a game on facebook. Post a picture on my page wall and someone, who shares this picture win my product.

This game is very famous, and over than 1500 people share the pic.

How can I export the list show who shared the picture?

Best regards,
Gabor

Comment: You'll get more answers and better help generally if you try something first and then post code that we can help you with. Best of luck!

Comment: You probably violating platform policies (partially outlined in existing answer) in what you do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a object via the Graph API (e.g. `http://graph.facebook.com/{object_id)`, Facebook only give you information on `Likes` and `Comments`. It does not show information on Sharing, so what you are asking is not possible.

You can try `http://graph.facebook.com/{object_id)/shares`, but it doesn't work, unlike `http://graph.facebook.com/{object_id)/likes` or `http://graph.facebook.com/{object_id)/comments`

In addition, it's against Facebook Platform Policy to "give away" something using Native Facebook functionality. That means, giving something away for Liking, Commenting or Sharing is not allowed.

> You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use
>   of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly
>   tied to the use of our channels.

Also:

> You must not use Facebook features or functionality, such as the Like button, as a voting mechanism for a promotion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried the likes with the graph api, but only the first 25 show for me.
How can I get the full results in one output?

Comment: Facebook only returns a limited amount of data per call. At the end of the result set, you will see a `paging` object that has the API calls to get the 'next' and 'previous' pages of the result set. You need to loop through the 'next' calls until you get to the end of the data.

Comment: Or you could just add ?limit=<number> to the end of the URL and get everything at once